# How to get background from cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection, background-subtraction

Is there any way to obtain background from cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in python?

In other words, is there any technique to compute an image based on last n frames of a video, which can be used as background?

Comment: What version of opencv are you using?  You can check by looking at `cv2.__version__`.

Comment: I use opencv 2.4.13

Answer (score 0):

Such a technique would be pretty complicated, but you might want to look at some keywords: image-stitching, gradient-based methods, patch-match, image filling. Matlab, for example, [has a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifill.html) that tries to interpolate missing values from nearby pixels. You could extend this method to work with 3D (shouldn't be so difficult in linear case).

More generally, it is sort of an ill-posed problem since there is no way to know what goes in the missing region.

Specifically to address your question, you might first take the difference between the original frame, and the extracted image, which should reveal the background. Then, use ROI fill in or similar method. There is likely some examples you can find on the web, such as [this](https://github.com/f3anaro/computer-vision-2/blob/master/1-patch-match/patchmatch.py).